# How to install a package in Laravel that has a higher version dependency requirement than Laravel requirements?

Tags: laravel, dependencies, composer-php

I am trying to install Rubix ML with latest Laravel version. Problem is Laravel wants lower version of `league/filesystem`, while Rubix ML wants a higher version.

How can I fix this without manually modifying each dependencies composer.json file which would be overwritten in future updates anyways?

```
Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires rubix/ml ^0.4.0 -> satisfiable by rubix/ml[0.4.0].
    - rubix/ml 0.4.0 requires league/flysystem ~2.0.2 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4] but the package is fixed to 1.1.3 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

Comment: Why not update `league/flysystem`? Otherwise, why not use `rubix/ml` in v0.2.4 which does not require Flysystem after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase I cannot update `league/flysystem` because Laravel composer requires lower version, and that's latest Laravel version. I did see that I could use lower version of `Rubix/ML` but I didn't want to miss out on any features. I wanted to know if there's a way to use latest versions of Rubix and Laravel and reconcile the dependencies somehow.

Comment: As there are multiple breaking changes between Flysystem v1 and v2, I don't see any simple way. Why not ask the maintainers of `rubix/ml` if they could add support for v1?

Comment: @NicoHaase certainly a good idea. Or ask Laravel devs to upgrade to v2. I just wanted to ask if composer had a way to reconcile this someway so that it is usable right away. In the mean time, I suppose I'll just use my forked Rubix ML library with lowered dependency and see how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: No, Composer has no way to resolve such library conflicts. If the code is incompatible, the code it incompatible

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So far I've been able to fork the `Rubix ML` repo, change the requirements to match `Laravel` and then add that Github repo in composer.  I'm not sure if that will break anything in Rubix ML, but hopefully it won't. I'll wait for someone to give a better answer if there is one.

As @NicoHaase confirmed, looks like there's not a better solution other than asking developers of either `Laravel` or `Rubix ML` to create versions that are compatible with older/newer `Flysystem` library.